# Unable to call a python script from Jenkinsfile

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I would like to run a python file from jenkinsfile.build pipeline file
my jenkinsfile.build file has many stages and from one stage i would like to run a python script
the format of my jenkinsfile.build is

```
stages{
        stage('Build stage') {
            steps {
                echo "${username}"
                dir("py_scripts"){
                    python -u say_hello.py --name '${username}'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy stage') {
         --------some code-------
        }
    }
}
```

and i have my python code which accepts an argument --name. That is running completely fine.
when i Run the jenkins job, i am seeing i get the error in console output of jenkins which denotes the line where i am calling the python script.
the error is

```
18:48:52  WorkflowScript: 26: expecting '}', found 'say_hello' @ line 26, column 31.
18:48:52                         python -u say_hello.py --name '${username}'
18:48:52                                   ^
18:48:52  
18:48:52  1 error
```

i need to change the command i am using to call the python script in jenkinsfile.
please help me in this. I am new to this Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the python script as a shell script inside a `sh` step:

```
sh "python -u say_hello.py --name '${username}'"
```

Comment: Or as a `bat` step if running on a Windows agent

Comment: Please help me on this. I have executed your code. it gives me usage: say_hello.py [-h] --name NAME
12:14:38  say_hello.py: error: the following arguments are required: --name

Comment: First of all, the Python script obviously gets executed now and the error is coming from the script execution itself. Is the variable `username` not an empty string? What do you see in the console output when the `echo "${username}"` statement is executed? You may also want to try to replace the `${username}` in the Python call with a literal value in order to rule out errors in the Python script itself.